# C++ class inhertance from template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visual-studio-2017

Hello i'm new to `c++` and i have a homework that requires a template `class`
called `ShiftCipher` which doesn't matter what it does and its syntax is completely right and compiling good :

```
#ifndef _SHIFTCHIPHER_
#define _SHIFTCIPHER_
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define NUM_OF_CHARS 26
#define ZERO 0
#define FIRST 'a'
#define LAST 'z'
 template<int key> class ShiftCipher{
public:
std::string encrypt(std::string& str)
{
    int length = str.length();
    char* newstr = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= FIRST && str[i] <= LAST)
        {
            if ((str[i] + key - FIRST) > NUM_OF_CHARS)
            {
                newstr = char(str[i] + key - NUM_OF_CHARS);
            }
            else
                if ((str[i] + key - FIRST) < ZERO)
                {
                    newstr = char(str[i] + key + NUM_OF_CHARS);
                }
                else
                    newstr[i] = char(str[i] + key);
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
std::string decrypt(std::string& str)
{
    int length = str.length(),key2=-1*key;
    char* newstr = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= FIRST && str[i] <= LAST)
        {
            if ((str[i] + key2 - FIRST) > NUM_OF_CHARS)
            {
                newstr = char(str[i] + key2 - NUM_OF_CHARS);
            }
            else
                if ((str[i] + key2 - FIRST) < ZERO)
                {
                    newstr = char(str[i] + key2 + NUM_OF_CHARS);
                }
                else
                    newstr[i] = char(str[i] + key2);
        }
    }
    return newstr;
}
};

#endif // !_SHIFTCHIPHER_
```

And then i have the `class` `SubstitutionChipher` which also works good and has no special thing such as templates or inheritance or anything else.
and the last thing is the `OperationsRoom` class which has to inheir from the two classes mentioned before :

```
#ifndef OPERATIONSROOM_H_
#define OPERATIONSROOM_H_
#define ZERO 0
#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define FOUR 4
#define FIVE 5
#define SIX 6
#define MAX_MSGS_NUMBER 2
#define FIRST_SHIFT_LENGTH 5
#define SECOND_SHIFT_LENGTH 10
#define THIRD_SHIFT_LENGTH 15
#define MALICIOUSE_WORD "SpongeBob"
#include"ShiftCipher.h"
#include"SubstitutionCipher.h"
class OperationsRoom :public SubstitutionCipher, public ShiftCipher<int key>
{
 int counter, flag;
 public:
OperationsRoom() 
{
    counter = ZERO;
    flag = ZERO;
}
void getMsg(std::string& msg)
{
    std::string newmsg;
    if (counter > SIX*MAX_MSGS_NUMBER)
    {
        counter = ZERO;
        flag = ZERO;
    }
    if ((counter >= ZERO && counter < MAX_MSGS_NUMBER) || (counter >= TWO * MAX_MSGS_NUMBER && counter < THREE*MAX_MSGS_NUMBER)
        || (counter >= FOUR * MAX_MSGS_NUMBER && counter < FIVE*MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
    {
        newmsg = SubstitutionCipher::decrypt(msg);
    }
    else
        if ((counter >= MAX_MSGS_NUMBER && counter < TWO*MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
        {
            ShiftCipher<FIRST_SHIFT_LENGTH> shifting;
            newmsg = shifting.decrypt(msg);
        }
        else
            if ((counter >= THREE * MAX_MSGS_NUMBER && counter< FOUR*MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
            {
                ShiftCipher<SECOND_SHIFT_LENGTH> shifting;
                newmsg = shifting.decrypt(msg);
            }
            else
                if ((counter >= FIVE * MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
                {
                    ShiftCipher<THIRD_SHIFT_LENGTH> shifting;
                    newmsg = shifting.decrypt(msg);
                }
    int found = newmsg.find(MALICIOUSE_WORD);
    if (found != -1)
        flag = ONE;
    std::cout << "A new message has been received.\n";
    if (flag && !((counter + ONE) % MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
    {
        flag = ZERO;
        std::cout << "Maliciouse detected!\n";
    }
    else
        if (!flag && !((counter + ONE) % MAX_MSGS_NUMBER))
        {
            flag = ZERO;
            std::cout << "Maliciouse wasnt detected!\n";
        }
 }
};
#endif
```

so it keeps giving me errors such as :

> error C2146: syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'key'.
>
> error C2993: 'int': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'key'
>
> error C2993: 'int': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'key'
>
> error C2955: 'ShiftCipher': use of class template requires template argument list

note: see declaration of `ShiftCipher`
i have looked in the forum about these errors but none of them helped me so i would be glad for some help.
and i think the real problem is in the definition of the class `OperationsRoom` with the using of the template.

Comment: sorry, but thats a funny way to avoid magic numbers. Isnt `ZERO` just as magic as `0` ?

Comment: `public ShiftCipher<int key>` should be `public ShiftCipher<SomeKey>` with `SomeKey` constexpr value.

Comment: @user463035818: that allows to redefine `ZERO` as `42` in one place :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I thought the same. Actually `ZERO` is way more magic than `0`

Comment: `#ifndef _SHIFTCHIPHER_
#define _SHIFTCIPHER_`  there is a typo CHIPHER and CIPHER

Answer (score 0):

you need to inherit from specific instance of ShiftCipher. Remember OperationRoom is not template, so it need to inherit specific instance only.

instead of

```
class OperationsRoom :public SubstitutionCipher, public ShiftCipher<int key>
```

you give actual key.. for example if key is 67

```
class OperationsRoom :public SubstitutionCipher, public ShiftCipher<67>
```

or you need to create template for OperationRooms if you want to generalize OperationRooms for any key: something like

```
template<int key>
class OperationsRoom :public SubstitutionCipher, public ShiftCipher<key>
```

Comment: *`template<int key>` I presume?